# List index out of range on python

Tags: python

im trying to make some procedure with parameter as a value that processed inside the function, but there's some problem. Here's some of my code

```
.
.
.
.
def pokerBruteForce(n:int, kombinasi:list, kartu:list, komposisi:list):
    c = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0
    l = 0
    m = 0
    done:bool
    teks:str
    if n <= 5:
        pass
    c = 0
    i = 0
    for i in range(n-1):
        done = False
        if ((n - c) > 4) and (kombinasi[i] == False):
            for j in range(i+1,(n - 1), 1):
                if kombinasi[j] == False and (((n - c) - 1) > 3):
                    if kartu[j].bobotCorak == kartu[i].bobotCorak and kartu[j].nilai == kartu[i].nilai - 1:
                        for k in range((i+1),(n - 1), 1):
                            if kombinasi[k] == False and (((n - c) - 2) > 2):
.
.
.
.
```

and the main code is

```
cards = []
combination = [False] * 5 
composition = []
createKartu(cards)
pokerBruteForce(7, combination, cards, composition)
for i in range(len(composition)):
    print(composition[i],)
```

while trying to compile and run the program, there're an error, it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\xxx\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxxx", line 330, in <module>
    pokerBruteForce(7, combination, cards, composition)
  File "d:\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxx\xxxxx", line 54, in pokerBruteForce
    if kombinasi[j] == False and (((n - c) - 1) > 3):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

i'm trying to trace the code back manually in the looping on j variable and i think i'm right. But it always say that its error. Maybe any solution?
thanks

Comment: To eliminate the obvious: is the value of the `n` argument larger than the size of the `kombinasi` list argument?

Comment: Indexes in `kombinasi` are from 0 to 4. `for i in range(n-1):` goes from 0 to 5. So `for j in range(i+1,(n - 1), 1):` can get above 4, which will cause a list index out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `kombinasi = [False]*5` and you try to access `kombinasi[5]`.
Remember that list indexes start from `0`, so you can only access `kombinasi[4]`.

You should use `j-1` in the following line :

```
for j in range(i+1,(n - 1), 1):
    if kombinasi[j-1] == False and (((n - c) - 1) > 3):
```

Or iterate `j` from `i`to `(n-2)`:

```
for j in range(i,(n - 2), 1):
    if kombinasi[j] == False and (((n - c) - 1) > 3):
```